# Python TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, linux, time, module

I run a piece of code on my mac in IDLE and it works fine. But when I tried to run the same code on a linux machine from the command line it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 1, in <module>
    import time

File "/home/ugrad/user/time.py", line 3, in <module>

t1 = time.time()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

here is the code:

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
size = 10000000
for i in range(size):
    a = i
    a += 100
    a *= 35
    val = (a == 839248637)
t2 = time.time()
res = t2-t1
print(res)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you named file `time.py` so now `import time` loads your file instead Python `time` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your file `time.py` so now `import time` loads your file instead Python `time` module. Change name to different - ie. `time-test.py`